# beautiful soup returns close tag instead of tag text

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have the following rss feed (soundcloud) http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:7393028/sounds.rss :

```
<item>
      <pubDate>Mon, 05 Jun 2017 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>https://example.com</link>
<item>
```

I attempt to get the link tag contents with the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")


items = soup.findAll("item")
for i in items:
    print i
    created_at = i.find('pubdate')
    created_at = created_at.contents[0][:16]

    url = i.find('link')

This prints:

    <link/>
```

If I try `url = i.find('link').string` or `url = i.find('link').content`

I get

> None

When I print the "i" item it prints a close tag first for link:

https://soundcloud.com/daptone-records/sharon-jones-the-dap-kings-white-christmas
      00:02:23
Daptone Records
no
Sharon Jones & the Dap-Kings' first ever holiday album is out now!

How can I get the link to open properly?

Comment: can you provide exact URL?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I added the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this and it'll do the job:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:7393028/sounds.rss'
data = urlopen(url).read()

parsed = bs(data, 'xml')
items = parsed.findAll('item')

for k in items:
    # Here is how you can access to the tags inside item tag
    print("Link:", k.link.text)
    print("pubDate:", k.pubDate.text)
```

**Edit: Using `lxml`**

When i try to parse the `<link>...</link>` tag using `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml` i got an invalid tag. Every link's tag begins by `</link>` and `BeautifulSoup` can't manage to parse its data.

So, an easy hack is using `regex`, here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url = 'http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:7393028/sounds.rss'
data = urlopen(url).read()

soup = bs(data, 'lxml')
aa = soup.findAll('item')

for k in aa:
    link = re.findall('<link/>(.*?)\s+', str(k))
    pubdate = k.find('pubdate').string
    print("Link: {}\npubdate: {}".format(' '.join(link), pubdate))
```

Both methods will output:

```
Link: https://soundcloud.com/daptone-records/move-upstairs
pubDate: Tue, 21 Mar 2017 20:30:49 +0000
...
Link: https://soundcloud.com/daptone-records/the-frightnrs-id-rather-go-blind-1
pubDate: Sun, 28 Jun 2015 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: is this possible with LXML?

Comment: I may change the code if it's with `LXML`. i'll update my answer

Comment: yeah thats what I ended up doing.  I guess beautiful soup doesn't play nice with sound cloud or those link tags.

Comment: But using `xml` it's smooth an easy. I tried using this [tutorial](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) but without any success. I guess there is something to add or modify when we use `lxml` it's a bit different than `xml` parser. But, hopefully regex can solve this issue ... for now.